# Allow for iframe to load before getting as application/pdf google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, html-email, attachment, export-to-pdf

How can I convert a [html output](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) using an iframe tag to application/pdf format but only after the contents are fully loaded.

Here's the code I'm using as of now

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<iframe src="https://..." width='100%' height='100%'/>`).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
var newBlob = htmlOutput.getAs('application/pdf')
var blobArray = [newBlob]
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "...",
    subject: "Test",
    Body: "pfa",
    attachments : blobArray
  });
```

I just end up with a pdf slide with a box; similar to am iframe that's not fully loaded

Comment: You need to implement a headless web browser. Better to use a different approach.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Rubén Perhaps you are right

Comment: @Vayun Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. From `Sadly that gives a similar result`, I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful for your situation. So, I have to delete my answer because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I think that I have to study more.

Comment: @Tanaike You're too kind! I deeply appreciate your time and effort.